# Pandas: Check whether a column exists in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

I am new to Python and pandas. I have a dataset that has the following structures. It is a pandas DF

```
city time1              time2
a    [1991, 1992, 1993] [1993,1994,1995]
```

time1 and time2 represnts the coverage of the data in two sources. I would like create a new column that indicates whether time1 and time2 have any intersection, if so return True otherwise False. The task sound very straightforward. I was thinking about using set operations on the two columns but it did not work as expected. Would anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through all the columns and change the lists to sets and see if there is are any values in the intersection.

```
df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: set(x) if type(x) == list else set([x]))
df1.apply(lambda x: bool(x.time1 & x.time2), axis=1)
```

This is a semi-vectorized way that should make it run much faster.

```
df1 = df[['time1', 'time2']].applymap(lambda x: set(x) if type(x) == list else set([x]))
(df1.time1.values & df1.time2.values).astype(bool)
```

And even a bit faster

```
change_to_set = lambda x: set(x) if type(x) == list else set([x])
time1_set = df.time1.map(change_to_set).values
time2_set = df.time2.map(change_to_set).values
(time1_set & time2_set).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work well. However, for a subset of my data, I encounter an exception called "'float' object is not iterable""

Comment: @macintosh81This means you have some years not in a list. You can convert each value in your dataframe to a set first and then use apply.

Comment: @macintosh81 The solution is now vectorized and much faster

Answer (score 2):

Here is kind of ugly, but vectorized approach:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
  city               time1               time2
0    a              [1970]              [1980]
1    b  [1991, 1992, 1993]  [1993, 1994, 1995]
2    c  [2000, 2001, 2002]        [2010, 2011]
3    d        [2015, 2016]              [2016]

In [38]: df['x'] = df.index.isin(
    ...:             pd.DataFrame(df.time1.tolist())
    ...:               .stack().reset_index(name='x')
    ...:               .merge(pd.DataFrame(df.time2.tolist())
    ...:                        .stack().reset_index(name='x'),
    ...:                      on=['level_0','x'])['level_0'])
    ...:

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
  city               time1               time2      x
0    a              [1970]              [1980]  False
1    b  [1991, 1992, 1993]  [1993, 1994, 1995]   True
2    c  [2000, 2001, 2002]        [2010, 2011]  False
3    d        [2015, 2016]              [2016]   True
```

**Timing:**

```
In [54]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [55]: df.shape
Out[55]: (40000, 3)

In [56]: %%timeit
    ...: df.index.isin(
    ...:   pd.DataFrame(df.time1.tolist())
    ...:     .stack().reset_index(name='x')
    ...:     .merge(pd.DataFrame(df.time2.tolist())
    ...:              .stack().reset_index(name='x'),
    ...:            on=['level_0','x'])['level_0'])
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 253 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: bool(set(x.time1) & set(x.time2)), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.36 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Does vectorized mean that it is faster?

Comment: @macintosh81, yes, usually it's faster - see `Timing` in the updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much for the timing experiment. Strangely, the vectorized version is slower on my computer.